# Is there a way of getting an iteration of columns in excel vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to continue this pattern for 52 columns for every week of the year for multiple sheets. All of the sheets are sorted and have the same format and so I can activate the macro with the activation of the sheets. Or potentially put a button in the summary tab to sort the lot.

Here is the code I have so far: I want to repeat both sets for 52 rows without building separate lines for each column.

Sub Macro1

```
Dim myC As Range
Set myC = ActiveCell

ActiveSheet.Range("C77:BB77").Select

    
Range("C77").Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$54,C49:C76)"
Range("D77").Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$54,D49:D76)"
Range("E77").Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$54,E49:E76)"
Range("F77").Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$54,F49:F76)"
Range("G77").Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$54,G49:G76)"

ActiveSheet.Range("C78:BB78").Select

Range("C78").Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$55,C49:C76)"

myC.Select
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use a For Each loop: `For Each Col in myRange.Columns` or you can use a regular For loop `For c = 1 to 52: Set col = myRange.Columns(c)`

Comment: In my answer, I assumed that 52 rows was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I think this will work well as well. You were right that it needed to be columns all the way

Answer (score 2):

Because the formula is relative, you can apply the formula to all the columns at one time:

> ```
> Range("C77").Resize(1, 52).Formula = "=sumcolouredCells($B$54,C49:C76)"
> ```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Now to finalise the project.

Comment: Could you tick the answer as accepted if this is the accepted answer.  It lets people know there's no need to look at the question any more.